# No Emails Received From My Site

Tags: php, wordpress, email, notifications, contact-form-7

i'm having problem with my site email functionality. i can't receive any emails like registration of new user, new comments etc.

I have used contact form 7 plugin to send mails from my contact form but it just gives success message but no mails are received.

I googled and found some solutions like changing receivers email id, deactivating specific plugin and then checking, ticking notify me checkbox in settings etc but none worked.

Can this be server issue or theme? Please can some one point me in right direction.

i'm using classicraft theme and wordpress 3.8.3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried sending the emails to another email address to see if the emails will be received by that address?

Comment: This is almost 100% a server based issue. Assuming your contact forms use wp_mail, try installing a wordpress smtp mail plugin, and configuring an SMTP server.

Alternatively, contact your web host and ask if PHP's mail() function is supported

Comment: Hi @howlin i tried sending email with other email address but no success

Comment: Hi @RichardDenton i tried sending mail from my server and mail is received in my inbox but when i send it via my site it doesn't so i guess this is not a server issue

Comment: Sounds like a PHP config error, or sendmail config error.

Comment: @RichardDenton: Then what do you suggest on that

Comment: Contact web host and ask them to investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have Got Answer to my Question it was a theme issue which was blocking messages to be sent i installed wp-smtp plugin and configured it following instructions which can be found   [here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smtp/) Thanks all for help may this help some one.